# Restrict dashboard access for specific user roles to specific actions

Tags: admin, user-roles, user-access

I have a script that enables a logged in user (role Author) to delete their own posts using `get_delete_post_link()`. However, I also want to be able to restrict the author's access to the dashboard. Any attempt to do so using a plugin (Theme my Login, for example) or a simple script like those linked below disables my ability to use `get_delete_post_link()`. Is there a way to restrict access to the dashboard for the "Author" user role while still permitting the deletion of posts via `get_delete_post_link()`?

http://www.tutorialstag.com/restrict-wordpress-dashboard-access.html

[How to restrict dashboard access to Admins only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11244/how-to-restrict-dashboard-access-to-admins-only)

Comment: How do the authors write the posts?

Comment: I've created a submit form on the front end that allows users to add a post. When the form is submitted it runs a script that uses wp_insert_post().

Comment: Toscho, this got me thinking that I should try to create a function using a similar method to the insert post function on my submit form to delete the post and it worked like a charm. Thanks for getting me to think about this a little differently!

Comment: Good to see you found a way. :) May I ask you to share your solution with us? Write an answer ↓, collect upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving this issue. Originally I used this code for the link to delete an individual post:

```
<?php if( !(get_post_status() == 'trash') ) : ?>
<a class="delete-post" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete post: <?php echo get_the_title() ?>?')"href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ); ?>">Delete</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After checking to see if the user was logged in and if the user was the author of this post. This didn't work as mentioned in my original post.

Instead I used a simple delete button (with the same checks as mentioned above):

```
<form class="delete-post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/edit-post" method="post"> 
    <input id="post_id" type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

and this jQuery script to make an ajax call that will run my php script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
    $('.delete-post').bind('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var post_id;
        post_id = $("#post_id").val();
        var data = {};
        var obj = {data: data}; 
        data['post_id'] = post_id;

        alert('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?');
        process_delete_post();

        function process_delete_post() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: run_delete_post.ajaxurl,
                data: ({
                    post_id : data['post_id'],
                    action : 'run_delete_post_script',
                }),
                success: function() {
                     location.href = "";
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Time out error.');
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }

            });
        }   

    }); 

});
```

In my functions.php file, I set up my ajax call:

```
function mytheme_delete_post() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'edit-delete-posts.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'process-delete-post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/process-delete-post.js', array('jquery'), true);
        wp_localize_script( 'process-delete-post', 'run_delete_post', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
        }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mytheme_delete_post');

$dirName = dirname(__FILE__);
$baseName = basename(realpath($dirName));
require_once ("$dirName/functions_custom.php");

add_action("wp_ajax_run_delete_post_script", "run_delete_post_script");
```

And then, the actual php script to delete the post in my functions_custom.php file:

```
function run_delete_post_script() {
    // Test for current user
    mytheme_get_current_user();

    //Get the data from the submit page and convert to php variables
    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
            $$field = $value;
        }
    }
    wp_delete_post( $post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a targeted redirect when an Author attempts to view the dashboard?

```
function restrict_dashboard_access() {
    //Leave AJAX requests alone - their life is hard enough without further scrutany
    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' )
        return;

    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/post.php' && isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            case 'trash': //Leave alone requests to delete posts,
            case 'delete'://such as those generated by get_delete_post_link()
                return;
        }
    }

    //For all other admin requests,

    //redirect users of the 'author' role to the home_url
    $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    if( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;  //Force script death to avoid useless script execution post-redirect
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_dashboard_access', 1 );
```

(Hacked together from your linked resources and [the WP Codex page for the `admin_init` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init))

**EDIT:** How to implement post-deletion redirect to a specific URL in light of the additional information provided in the comments:

```
function restrict_dashboard_access() {
    //Leave AJAX requests alone - their life is hard enough without further scrutany
    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' )
        return;

    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/post.php' && isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            case 'trash': //Leave alone requests to delete posts,
            case 'delete'://such as those generated by get_delete_post_link()
                return;
        }
    }

    //For all other admin requests, redirect users of the 'author' role
    $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    if( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {

        if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/edit.php' && ( isset( $_REQUEST['trashed'] ) || isset( $_REQUEST['deleted'] ) ) ) {
            // If an Author has just deleted a post - redirect them to a specific URL.
            wp_redirect( home_url() . '/post-deleted-page' );
        } else {
            // If an Author is viewing any other admin page, drop them back to the homepage
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
        }

        exit;  //Force script death to avoid useless script execution post-redirect
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_dashboard_access', 1 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. It still redirects me when I try to delete a post as an author.

Comment: @clampdesign I believe it works exactly as I intended it, and furthermore fulfills the parameters of your question. Author users will still be redirected because a successful post deletion request sent to `wp-admin/post.php?action=delete` will redirected to `wp-admin/edit.php`. As access to `edit.php` has been entirely restricted from the Author user role by this very block of code, they are immediately kicked back to `home_url()`. Regardless of the redirect, I think you'll find that the post has indeed been successfully deleted.

Comment: Adding a case to check if the page is `wp-admin/edit.php` in order to redirect to your choice of URL after a successful deletion is a minor modification. I have appended the necessary edits to do so.

Comment: I did try this and it did not delete the post, unfortunately.

Comment: Strangeness my friend - it works on my end. Sorry to hear it, but glad you found a functional solution :)