# Deny dashboard access breaks ajax requests

Tags: ajax, dashboard

I need to restrict the access to the dashboard fon non-admin. Therefore i'm using this function in the functions.php:

```
function ggp_restrict_dashboard_access_function() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')){
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'ggp_restrict_dashboard_access_function', 1);
```

Problem is that because of this, Ajax calls are returning a 301 for non logged in users as well as for logged in non-admin users.

How can i workaround this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict dashboard access to Admins only?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11244/how-to-restrict-dashboard-access-to-admins-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also check it's not an AJAX request inside your hook:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
```